# c# warn if  text box is empty or contains a non-whole number

Tags: c#, textbox, string

In my specific case, I need the value in propertyPriceTextBox to be numeric only, and a whole number. A value also has to be entered, and I can just Messagebox.Show() a warning and that's all I'd need to do.

This is what I have so far.

```
        private void computeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal propertyPrice;

        if ((decimal.TryParse(propertyPriceTextBox.Text, out propertyPrice)))
            decimal.Parse(propertyPriceTextBox.Text);
        {

            if (residentialRadioButton.Checked == true)



                commisionLabel.Text = (residentialCom * propertyPrice).ToString("c");



            if (commercialRadioButton.Checked == true)

                commisionLabel.Text = (commercialCom * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

            if (hillsRadioButton.Checked == true)

                countySalesTaxTextBox.Text = ( hilssTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

            if (pascoRadioButton.Checked == true)

                countySalesTaxTextBox.Text = (pascoTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

            if (polkRadioButton.Checked == true)

                countySalesTaxTextBox.Text = (polkTax * propertyPrice).ToString("c");

            decimal result;

                result = (countySalesTaxTextBox.Text + stateSalesTaxTextBox.Text + propertyPriceTextBox.Text + comissionTextBox.Text).ToString("c");
        }

        else (.)

            MessageBox.Show("Property Price must be a whole number.");
    }
```

Comment: It's been a while, but doesn't the `TextBox` control have some build-in validation capabilities that would prevent decimals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `decimal.TryParse` use `Int32.TryParse` this will return false if the value is a non integer:

```
int propertyPrice;
if (Int32.TryParse(propertyPriceTextBox.Text, out propertyPrice)
{
    // use propertyPrice
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Property Price must be a whole number.");
}
```

There's no need to call `Parse` again as `TryParse` does the conversion and returns true if it succeeds and false otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, you're an incredible man. Probably as good as superman.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way

```
   int outParse;

   // Check if the point entered is numeric or not
   if (Int32.TryParse(propertyPriceTextBox.Text, out outParse) && outParse)
    {
       // Do what you want to do if numeric
    }
   else
    {
       // Do what you want to do if not numeric
    }
```